# NestJS: custom logger undefined inside filter exception when throw error at middleware

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, nestjs

I have logger custom module, filter exception catch all error, middleware auth.
when I throw error in other module, logger module work ok in filter exception. But when throw error in middleware, `this.logger.fatal()` is undefined. Any suggestion please. Thank you

exception.filter.ts

```
@Catch()
export class AllExceptionsFilter implements ExceptionFilter {
  constructor(
    @Inject(forwardRef(() => LogController))
    private readonly logger: LogController) {
  }

  catch(exception: HttpException | Error, host: ArgumentsHost): void {

    const ctx: HttpArgumentsHost = host.switchToHttp();
    const response: Response = ctx.getResponse();
    const status = exception instanceof HttpException ? exception.getStatus() : 
    if (status >= 500) {
      this.logger.fatal(exception['message'], exception!.stack.toString())
    }

    if (status >= 400 && status < 500) {
      this.logger.error(exception['message'], exception!.stack.toString())
    }

    // Response to client
    AllExceptionsFilter.handleResponse(response, exception)
  }
}
```

auth.middleware.ts

```
export class AuthenticationMiddleware{
  async use(req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) {
    throw new HttpException({message: 'Authentication got error', status: 500},500)
  }
}
```

log.service.ts

```
@Injectable()
export class LogService {
  constructor(
  ) { }
  error(message: any, stack?: string) {
    console.log(`message::${message} - stack::${stack}`) });
  }

  fatal(message: any, stack?: string) {    
    console.log(`message::${message} - stack::${stack}`) }); });
  }
}
```

Comment: Why is `LogController` a `@Controller()`? Do you expect to call some endpoint to get the logs? And how do you use this `AllExceptionsFilter`?

Comment: @JayMcDoniel Hi, I updated the question. My purpose is ```AllExceptionsFilter``` will catch all exception in application and I will record log error right there. I test throw error at ```AppController``` then logger work ok, but when i throw error at middleware Auth then logger is undefined. As i check maybe middleware start before logger init this why return undefined. How I improve my logger for work with middleware. Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you should inject `LogService` into `AllExceptionsFilter`, not `LogController`.

In your `main.ts`

```
async function bootstrap() {
   const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);

   // resolve LogService
   const logService = app.get<LogService>(LogService);
   app.useGlobalFilters(new AllExceptionsFilter(logService));

   await app.listen(3000);
}

bootstrap();
```